# Differential Equations - Fluid

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> > Question: Fluid is being poured into a tank such that the volume $V$ $cm^3$ of fluid is related to the height $h$ cm of the fluid in the tank by $V= \frac{\pi h^3}{3}$. There are two sources of fluid. One is a constant flow of $0.5cm^3$ per second, the other is a source proportional to the height of fluid in the tank.
> >
> > When $h=1$ cm the rate of change with respect to time of $h$ is $1$$\frac{cm}{sec}$. It can be shown that the following is true : $h+1 = 2h^2 \frac{dh}{dt}$
> >
> > Find an equation connecting $h$ and $t$

My attempt;

$$h+1 = 2h^2 \frac{dh}{dt}$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \int dt = 2 \int \frac{h^2}{h+1} dh $$

$$  \Leftrightarrow \int dt = 2 \int h-1+\frac{1}{h+1} dh $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow t = 2\left[\frac{h^2}{2}-h + \ln|h+1| \right]+ C $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow t= h^2-2h+2\ln|h+1| + C $$

Which gives me one equation

Also we know that $\frac{dV}{dt} = 0.5$ and $\frac{dV}{dh}= \pi h^2$

So $$ \frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{dh}{dV} \cdot \frac{dV}{dt} $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{1}{2\pi h^2}$$

$$ \int 2\pi h^2 ~dh = \int dt $$

$$\frac{2\pi h^3}{3}+C=t$$

Now I am stuck how should I proceed?

Comment: In the second equation you evaluated the effect of only the constant source, there is also a second source "proportional to the height of fluid in the tank".

Comment: @N74 how do I incorporate that into my equation?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* All you need to do is to use the given conditions in order to find $C$. You have the following things available to you:

\begin{align}
\frac{dh(t)}{dt}&=1 \quad \text{when } h(t)=1 \\
h(t)&=\left(\frac{3(t-C)}{2 \pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}
\end{align}

Have a go at it and let me know if you're still stuck after this.